# Creating a MySQL query using a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm developing a system that is used for booking resources per hour. For example booking a conference room by the hour or whatever. I've pretty much got all the functionality working but some things are far from perfect and there's one function that I've got that's bugging me. It's booking a resource for an entire week. My code for it is below but any help on making it more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Steve

```
function bookweek($week) {
global $deskid, $date, $time, $member_id, $bookingTimes, $day0, $day1, $day2, $day3, $day4, $day5, $day6, $day7, $day8, $day9, $day10, $day11, $day12, $day13;

dbconnect();

switch($week) {
    case 1: 
        $dupecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booked where deskid='$deskid' AND date>='$day0' AND date <'$day7'");        
        if (mysql_num_rows($dupecheck) == 0) 
        {
            for($j = 0; $j< 7; $j++) 
            {   
                $daynumber=$j;
                $testing = "day".$daynumber;
                $daytotal= $$testing;
            for($i = 1; $i < count($bookingTimes)+1; $i++) 
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO booked (date, time, deskid, member_id) VALUES ('$daytotal', '$i', '$deskid', '$member_id')";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    if (!$result) {
                        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
            }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        $dupecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booked where deskid='$deskid' AND date > '$day6'");         
        if (mysql_num_rows($dupecheck) == 0) 
        {
            for($j = 0; $j< 7; $j++) 
            {   
                $daynumber=$j+7;
                $testing = "day".$daynumber;
                $daytotal= $$testing;
            for($i = 1; $i < count($bookingTimes)+1; $i++) 
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO booked (date, time, deskid, member_id) VALUES ('$daytotal', '$i', '$deskid', '$member_id')";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    if (!$result) {
                        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
            }
            }
        }
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Just a note that this is not a command. You are talking about `query`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, absolutely right :P *slaps forehead*

Comment: Please use `mysqli` or `PDO` as opposed to mysql.

Comment: Please note: The `mysql_` are considered obsolete. The PHP manual recommends switching to either `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. [Here is a tutorial page that explains it all in detail](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Huh, was unaware of this. Sorry literally not touched PHP since about 2007... The whole world has changed since then! Thanks for the heads up on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be **hard to maintain** if used for any case the **whole sql block**.
Make it more efficient.

```
function bookweek($week) {
global $deskid, $date, $time, $member_id, $bookingTimes, $day0, $day1, $day2, $day3, $day4, $day5, $day6, $day7, $day8, $day9, $day10, $day11, $day12, $day13;

$queryP = "SELECT * FROM booked where deskid='".$deskid."' AND date>";
dbconnect();
switch($week) {
case 1: 
       $dupecheck = mysql_query($queryP."='".$day0."' AND date <'".$day7."'");      
       break;
case 2:
       $dupecheck = mysql_query($queryP."'".$day6."'");         
       break;
}
    if (mysql_num_rows($dupecheck) == 0) 
[...]
```

**And give mysqli a try**

Now the code is more clear and it is immediately apparent that things can be improved.

```
$queryP = "SELECT * FROM booked where deskid='".$deskid."' AND date>";
dbconnect();

switch($week) {
case 1: 
       $queryP .= "='".$day0."' AND date <'".$day7."'";
       break;
case 2:
       $queryP .= "'".$day6."'";
       break;
}
       $dupecheck = mysql_query($queryP);          
       if (mysql_num_rows($dupecheck) == 0) 
[...]
```

Let's come to the loop.
In order to better test on errors. I would change only the inner loop.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($dupecheck) == 0) 
  {
         for($j = 0; $j< 7; $j++) 
         {  
          $testing = "day".$j;
          $daytotal= $$testing;
          $sql = "INSERT INTO booked (date, time, deskid, member_id) VALUES ";
          $sqlTest = $sql;
          for($i = 1; $i < count($bookingTimes)+1; $i++) 
            {
              $sql .= "('".$daytotal."', '".$i."', '".$deskid."', '".$member_id."'),";
            }
          if ($sql == $sqlTest) {
                // nothing to be done or die
            } else {
            $sql = rtrim($sql,",");    
            result = mysql_query($sql);
              if (!$result) {
                 die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
              }
           }
         }
 }
```

Comment: It's beautiful, thanks! Was exactly what I wanted it to be, just had no idea how to. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Glad to help. Not too long work with past methods. Read all about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) you will save much MySQL resources.